# Convergence in $L^1$ of Poisson distribution

Tags: probability

Let $N_n$ be a Poisson distribution with parameter $n$. Check if $\frac{N_n}{n} \to 1$ in $L^1$.

All I have to do is to compute $\mathbb{E}|\frac{N_n}{n} - 1|$, but this absolute value seems problematic to me. Can I calculate it in some quick way or do I have to compute expected value in the standard way ($\sum k\mathbb{P}(|\frac{N_n}{n} - 1| = k)$ )?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{E}[N_n]=n=\mathrm{var}(N_n)$, we have
$$ \mathbb{E}\Big[\Big(\frac{N_n}{n}-1\Big)^2\Big]=\frac{1}{n^2}\mathbb{E}[(N_n-n)^2]=\frac{\mathrm{var}(N_n)}{n^2}=\frac{1}{n}\to0$$
as $n\to\infty$.

Therefore $\frac{N_n}{n}\to1$ in $L^2$, hence $\frac{N_n}{n}\to 1$ in $L^1$.

Comment: So generally, testing if some random variable converges in $L^1$ is much less convenient and its better to try looking at convergence in $L^2$?

Comment: @Barabara For what it's worth: $L^p$ convergence implies $L^q$ convergence as long as $p>q$. Proof $$\|f\|_q^q\le E(|f|^q\cdot 1)\le E(|f|^p)^{q/p}E(1^{w})^{1/w}=\|f\|_p^q$$ where $w>1$ satisfies $1/w+q/p=1$, by Hölder's inequality.

Comment: Yes, $L^2$ is often more convenient if it's applicable.